# Sanatize one category from the admin categories column

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently creating a store using WooCommerce, and as part of that I have set up a function to add a 'New In' category to every new product that is added (this is so that i can use WooCommerces built in category listing page to display items that have been added most recently, setting this page to automatically sort by newest item).

I have also added a function that hides this category to all users, as they have no need to know that this category has been added, however, it does not remove it from the category column in the product listings. It is removed everywhere else, and all works. I wondered if there was a way to get the information from the column and filter it prior to display? So that I could remove the unwanted category. As you can see from the picture below, the 'New In' category is displaying here. It does not display anywhere else.

[image: This is the area I want to remove it from, it does not show anywhere else aside from here.]

Cheers

Andy

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you're doing, but couldn't you accomplish displaying new items via the [shortcodes](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/) build into WooCommerce?

Comment: Unfortunately, Woocommerce shortcodes don't allow for pagination and filtering (my initial hope was to use the built in shortcodes for this). After lots of researching the best way to do the 'New In' page this I think is the best approach.

The only thing wrong with it is literally this last thing, hiding the category on the column view (if push comes to shove I will just leave it be, but wanted to check if anyone knew of a good way to sanatise the output first).